# how do i can solve the "main java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster" and others conflicts?

Tags: java

1 problem

Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster

```
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)

at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
```

2 problem

```
public Spritesheet(String path) {
    try {
        spritesheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public BufferedImage getSprite(int x,int y,int width, int height) {
    return spritesheet.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

3 problem

```
    rightPlayer[i] = Game.spritesheet.getSprite(112 +(i*16), 16, 16, 16);
```

4 problem

```
        player = new Player(0,0,16,16,spritesheet.getSprite(48, 0, 16, 16));
```

sorry if you guys dont understand, im new on this.

Comment: The error is trying to tell you that you’re requesting a portion of the image which is beyond the bounds of the image

Comment: then what should i do?
resize the image?
or change the values?

Comment: You need to make sure that the area you’re requesting is within the bounds of the image